# Issue pushing large number of messages in Cassandra from spark streaming using cassandra spark connector (java)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have been trying to push large number of json messages (around 2KB each), to cassandra, coming from kafka to spark streaming.

Simulator---->Kafka---->SparkStreaming--->Cassandra.

Each of these are running on separate ec2 instances with 30GB of Ram and 8 core processor as standalone single node setup.

When, I am trying to push around 5 million messages from simulator, after around 100k messages, cassandra stops inserting messages, and spark streaming job just keeps creating batches (as seen in the spark streaming web ui). I have even checked the logs but didn't find any issues there.

Also, i am not sure about the way i am using the spark connector in the code for writing to cassandra.

please see the code below,

```
/**
 * Spark Streaming to cassandra code
 */

package org.sparkexample;



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class SparkStreamingKafkaTest {


private SparkStreamingKafkaTest() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 6) {
        System.err.println("Usage: SparkStreamingKafka <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads> <conc write> <cassandra ip>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkStreamingKafka");




    //specific to cassandra

    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", args[4]);
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",args[5]);

    // Create the context with a 2 second batch size
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] topics = args[2].split(",");
    for (String topic : topics) {
        topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
    }

    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1],
            topicMap);

    JavaDStream<WordCount> wc = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, WordCount>() {

        @Override
        public WordCount call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
            String key = System.currentTimeMillis()+ "_"+ Math.random();
            return new WordCount(key, tuple2._2());
        }
    });

    Map <String, String> map =  new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("word", "word");
    map.put("count", "count");

    CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(wc).writerBuilder("mykeyspace", "wordcount",CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(WordCount.class, map)).saveToCassandra(); 

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
  }


  }
```

WordCount.java

```
  package org.sparkexample;

  import java.io.Serializable;

  public class WordCount implements Serializable{

  private String word;
  private String count;

  public WordCount(){

  }

  public String getWord() {
    return word;
  }
  public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }
  public String getCount() {
    return count;
  }
  public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  public WordCount(String key, String count) {
    this.word = key;
    this.count = count;
  }
  }
```

I have been using the default cassandra.yml with the following major dependencies,

- spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 - 1.4.0-M3
- spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 - 1.4.0-M3
- cassandra-driver-core - 2.1.7.1
- spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 - 1.4.1
- spark-streaming_2.10 - 1.4.1
- spark-core_2.10 - 1.4.1

Please suggest what can be the issue.

The output of the nodetool info and nodetool tpstats is as under.

[image: nodetool info]

[image: nodetool tpstat]